# I think I totally deleted a very important folder and I'm freaking out. How can I go back to old restore points?

Tags: linux, windows-7, backup, shared-folders

So I bought a new Notebook and installed Linux on it because I never used it and I wanted to try it. I used it for about two weeks before giving up yesterday and installing Windows 7, Linux is not for me. Anyway, while I used it, I shared a folder I had on one of my PCs with my Linux PC. Thing is, I think the folder was *stored* on the Linux PC and accessed through my other PC that is running Windows 7. When I deleted the disk on the Notebook to install Windows 7 I didn't backup that folder because I thought it was saved on my other PC. Turns out that right now, after installing Windows 7 on the Notebook, I realized the horrible thing I did. The freaking thing is nowhere to be found. I thought about using a restore point in the other PC to get to the point before I moved the folder to the Linux PC, but my restore points only go back to 19th May. I'm not 100% sure, but I'm almost positive the deed had already been done by that date. Does somebody know how can I go back even further if it is even possible? That folder had about 150 hours of important work, I really REALLY need it.

Comment: Based on the way you're putting it, you have two separate PCs? Also, if you installed Windows on the computer where you deleted your Linux distro and important folder already, there is very little chance of getting it back without data recovery software that is probably advanced.

Comment: Yes I have two PCs. I realize that I won't be able to get it back from the ex-linux PC, so I was looking for a way to revert to older windows restoration points so I can get back to the moment before I moved the folder. I was thinking, if I go back to the oldest one I have available (19th May), shouldn't I get access to previus restoration points from there?

Comment: You may be able to use System Restore to restore to your older system, but I doubt that you will be able to get access to older restore points. It's worth a shot though. It may happen

Comment: If your data was stored on the Linux system its most likely gone. Fragments may remain on the disk which might be recovetable - with significant effort using somethong like photorec, but from thebsound of it, it looks like your best option is to put aside 150 hours to redo the list work- it will be quicker (then partial recovery + recreation, and quicker because you already did it once) and likely higher quality the second time.